# Using SSH insteadof HTTPS just for fetch/clone

Tags: git, git-config

I would like do force all clone/pulls to get the data from SSH, but continue to use HTTPS for push.

My command will always use https (`git clone https://`) and I can´t change this (lot of scritps using) but I would like to force the clone to use SSH, and continue to use HTTPS for push.

What I did (in this order):

```
[url "ssh://server/"]
insteadOf = "https://server/"
[url "https://server/"]
pushInsteadOf = "ssh://server/"
```

But both fetch and push are being translated to SSH:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://server/repo.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://server/repo.git (push)
```

And I would like to see something like this:

```
$ git clone https://server/repo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://server/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://server/repo.git (push)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As strange as it seems, you'll need to translate https to https for it to work;

```
[url "ssh://server/"]
insteadOf = "https://server/"
[url "https://server/"]
pushInsteadOf = "https://server/"
```

Comment: Very cool... I've never seen the "insteadOf" bit.  New tool, thanks!

Comment: Perfect, Joachim!!! It worked! Really, really strange.... Git is always surprising me :)

Tks a lot!

Comment: Cool! I wouldn't expect this scenario to be common enough to grant a configuration option. I guess I really don't know most workflows people use :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `git remote  set-url --push`. From the documentation:

```
set-url
  Changes URL remote points to. Sets first URL remote points to
  matching regex <oldurl> (first URL if no <oldurl> is given)
  to <newurl>. If <oldurl> doesn’t match any URL, error occurs and
  nothing is changed.

    With --push, push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs.
    With --add, instead of changing some URL, new URL is added.
    With --delete, instead of changing some URL, all URLs matching
      regex <url> are deleted. Trying to delete all non-push URLs is an error.
```

Comment: Tks for your answer, Renato. It will work, but not for me :( I need something 100% transparent for the scripts. This 'git remote set-url' should be run after the clone, and I would like to avoid that because it will require a lot of script editing :)
I need something that demands to edit ~/.gitconfig only. All scripts run under the same user.